# Kendo ui grid datasource for nested json

Tags: json, kendo-ui

Lets say i had a json format like this

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('#grid').kendoGrid(
    {
        scrollable: false,
        dataSource: {data: [{ test: 1, data: [ { "TestHeader": "This is some test data"} ] }]},
        columns: [ { field: 'TestHeader' } ]
    });
});
```

how do i get the testHeader field to display on kendoui grid?
if the json data is like this

```
{ test: 1, data: [ { "TestHeader": "This is some test data"} ] }
```

it would work, but not if it is nested like this

```
{data: [{ test: 1, data: [ { "TestHeader": "This is some test data"} ] }]}
```

I can't control what server return, so i can't change the return json, so how can i get this done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it done already, using schema: parse on datasource
found it at here [How can I use nested Json to populate Kendo UI grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17231153/how-can-i-use-nested-json-to-populate-kendo-ui-grid)