# KendoUI Combobox Configure for Complex Objects

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-combobox

I am binding the Combobox to a complex Object, the binding is such that ID field is available as a direct property on this object but the Text Property is coming from a child objects property.

I have been able to configure it show the values correctly, ***but running into problem to specify the optionLabel saying "select" not able to specify Parent.Childproperty getting runtime error (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Childproperty' of undefined )***

How can i specify Complex Objects in the Model defination and below for the empty selection ?

```
   $('<input id="DegreeDDL" name="' + options.field + '"/>').appendTo(container).kendoDropDownList({
            autoBind: true,
            serverFiltering: true,
            optionLabel: {
                'Parent.Childproperty': "--- Select ---",
                ABCD_PK: null

            },
            dataSource: {
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        url: function (e) {
                            return "api/Org/XXXXXXXX?abcdPK=" + efgh;
                        },
                        dataType: "json" // <-- The default was "jsonp"
                    }
                },
            },
            dataTextField: "Parent.ChildProperty",
            dataValueField: "ABCD_PK"
        });
```

Also running into similar propblem when defining model for the grid

```
 var model = {
        id: "ABCD_PK",
        fields: {
            Parent.Child.ChilProperty: 
                }
             }
```

Comment: I don't wanna complain but this is DropDownList not ComboBOx as you mentioned in title, also in your code you have `dataTextField: "Parent.ChildProperty"` and then `Parent.Child.ChilProperty: ` with `Child` property after parent and without anything after colon. Please fix your code.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question: use optionLabel as string if creating object here causes errors:

```
optionLabel: "--- Select ---",
```

Here is working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a6Ek2/11/

To answer your second question just use `dataSource.schema` to parse your json for non complex object. More in this topic: [How can I use nested Json to populate Kendo UI grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17231153/how-can-i-use-nested-json-to-populate-kendo-ui-grid). Grid official do not working with complex data objects. But if you wanna give a try you delclare only parent object in model eg:

```
fields: {
    ABCD_PK: { editable: false },
    Parent: { editable: true },
}
```

If you still got problem with this just update this JSFiddle and show exacly where this is. I'll try improve my answers then.