# bind complex json to kendo grid

Tags: json, kendo-ui

I am facing problem in binding data in child objects in Kendo ui grid. My data looks like this

```js
{"Mydata":{"output":[{"Id":48,"Name":"abc"}]}
```

If the data is returned like

```js
{"Id":48,"Name":"abc"}
```

this I can easily bind. how can I bind data within child objects.? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Set in the DataSource `schema.data` to `Mydata.output`. Something like:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: ...
    },
    schema: {
        data: "Mydata.output"
    }
});
```

Comment: Onabai, thanks for your reply. I found another post by you and that worked great. Here is the link which did the trick. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17231153/how-can-i-use-nested-json-to-populate-kendo-ui-grid