# How can I mapping nested Json to Kendo UI grid?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I use a web api to send data to display in Kendo UI grid. my web api return a nested json.
As follows:

```
{
"SearchRequest": {
        "Term": null,
        "SortDirection": "Desc",
        "Total": 0,
        "PageIndex": 1,
        "PageSize": 10,
        "CurrentSort": null
    },
    "OperationalRisks": [
        {
            "LocationCode": 224.0,
            "RegisterDate": "1/01/01"
        },
        {
            "LocationCode": 211.0,
            "RegisterDate": "1/01/01"
        }
 ]
}
```

After that, I will try to display the data in the following way :

```
columns: [
                    { field: "OperationalRisks.LocationCode", title: "#" },
                    { field: "OperationalRisks.RegisterDate", title: "#" }
                ]
```

And:

```
schema: {
                    model: {
                        fields: {
                            "OperationalRisks.LocationCode": { type: "number" }, 
                            "OperationalRisks.RegisterDate": { type: "number" }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

But the data isn't bind to grid

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use nested Json to populate Kendo UI grid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17231153/how-can-i-use-nested-json-to-populate-kendo-ui-grid)

Comment: in this question no mention to how do I specify columns to the grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was easily solved and I would like to share this with you
first of all you should define:

```
var json_data;
```

and after that:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid{{
datasource:{
type:"json",
data:json_data.OperationalRisks,
.
.
.

columns: [
           { field: "LocationCode", title: "#" },
           { field: "RegisterDate", title: "#" }
         ],
.
.
.
schema: {
                    model: {
                        fields: {
                            "LocationCode": { type: "number" }, 
                            "RegisterDate": { type: "number" }
                        }
                    }
                }
```